# Can a Reference Name be same for same services in terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Can a Reference Name be same for same services in terraform?

Eg.

1st Load Balancer

```
resource "aws_lb" "front_end" {
   ...
}
```

2nd Load Balancer

```
resource "aws_lb" "front_end" {
   ...
}
```

`front_end` as a Reference Name for same service, is it valid?

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the same module: no, that is invalid. Just try it, you will get an error.

In separate modules: yes. Because the full name of the resource includes the module(s) and will be something like `module.something.aws_elb.front_end` vs e.g. `aws_elb.front_end` for the root module.